# search letters from wordlist and print words

Tags: python, python-2.7

i already created this program but facing some error . its showing those words which contain any letter from user input but i want it should search all letter in a word :
my code is

```
life=open('/Users/tim/Desktop/words.txt')
dds=str(input())
for list in life:
    index=0


    if dds[index] in list:
        print(list)
    index=index+1
```

which modifications i have to do so it can search as i want ?

and also i tried this :

```
 life=open('/Users/tim/Desktop/words.txt')
    dds="er"
    for list in life:
        index=0


        if dds[index] in list:
            print(list)
        index=index+1
```

now i wanted it should print all words containing word "e"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
if dds[index:] in list:
```

you were doing : `if dds[index] in list:` it means it will print all words which contains any letter of "dds" in word in wordlist . if you try this : `if dds[index:] in list:` it will search all letter of word in wordlist . `[:]` will select all letters

```
a[start:end] # items start through end-1
a[start:]    # items start through the rest of the array
a[:end]      # items from the beginning through end-1
a[:]         # a copy of the whole array
```

Comment: can you explain your answer ??

Comment: you were doing :

`if dds[index] in list:` it means it will print all words which contains any letter of "dds" in word in wordlist . 

if you try this :

`if dds[index:] in list:`

it will search all letter of word in wordlist . [:] will select all letters

Comment: Explain your answer by editing your answer, so other readers and especially the OP understand why this fixes the problem.

Comment: @exepaul any reference for [:] ??

Comment: Put the explanation in your answer @exepaul . Comments are easily missed by readers

Comment: @user325923 i explained . if you want more reference please visit 
`https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings`